# Passing touches to a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiresponder

I have one view that has 2 sub views, let's call it a parent view. Those 2 sub views (let them be A and B), overlap, A is covering a portion of B. B view has some buttons on it, one of which is covered by A. Since A background color is clear color, user can see that button, and might want to press it, but alas he can't.

In normal mode, if A was sub view of B, i could do something like this:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

   // pass touches to next responder in chain
   [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

But since that isn't a case how can i pass that touch to B?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[[self view] bringSubviewToFront:subview_B];
```